# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error,Error Code 0x800700b7

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

This question is already asked : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433148/how-to-solve-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-error-code-0x800700b7

Pls help this issue.

**The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.**

The Project works well on localhost , but when hosted in server we get the above error. Project URL : http://vancrm.fluead.com/

How to fix it ? I have attached a sample screenshot as follows : [image] :

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear. It says that your config file (web.config) contains system.web.extensions/scripting/scriptResourceHandler twice.

The reason why localhost is working fine might be the versions of the IIS. There are some parts of the config that are used prior to IIS 6.0 and below.